# Taxonomy picker control

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, taxonomy

In my SharePoint 2010 web part I want to display the control which allows to select the term - it is the same control that is being used when you have metadata column in your list and try to add new item, or when you use SharePoint 2010 tagging to tag the page it displays the control where you start to type the term name and it auto suggests you available terms.

Please, note, i am not asking about TaxonomyFieldEditor control, which the the big control for creating new term stores,etc, i just want the picker, which is used in lists and tagging.

Is that possible to add to my web part? If yes, then how?

Many Thanks